# C# VisualStudio 2012 - FreeLibrary() blocks the application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dllimport, loadlibrary

I am using DLLImport LoadLibrary() and FreeLibrary() in C# on 3 DLL.
I can Load the 3 DLL without any problem, but at the end of my application where I am using my FreeLibrary, it doesn't go further and I have to manually stop it.

This is a WPF Application, and I must call the 3 DLLs because they need eachothers. I cannot use the "Add Reference" to add the DLL.

Here is the code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            string pathDllOne = "dll/DllOne.dll";
            string pathDllTwo = "dll/DllTwo.dll";
            string pathDllThree = "dll/DllThree.dll";

            IntPtr DllThreeLink = LoadLibrary(pathDllThree);
            IntPtr DllTwoLink = LoadLibrary(pathDllTwo); 
            IntPtr DllOneLink = LoadLibrary(pathDllOne);

            if (DllOneLink == IntPtr.Zero || DllTwoLink == IntPtr.Zero || DllThreeLink == IntPtr.Zero)
                Console.WriteLine("WARNING : UNABLE TO FIND ONE OR MORE DLL");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("LOADING OK");

            FreeLibrary(DllThreeLink);
            FreeLibrary(DllTwoLink);
            FreeLibrary(DllOneLink);

            Console.WriteLine("END");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The console clearly shows the "LOADING OK".
The problem happened when I call "FreeLibrary(DllOneLink);". It doesn't go further, so it doesn't show the "END" message.
Do you have any idea what may cause this?

Comment: What are the return codes of the FreeLibrary calls? You can also narrow it down to the call which causes that by stepping through the program.

Comment: Run your application in a debugger and break the process when it "hangs". Then look at the stacks of the threads in your process to learn what they are waiting for. `FreeLibrary` may cause a deadlock because it acquires a critical section and if the `DllMain` of the DLL then waits for something that will only happen after the lock has been released you have a deadlock. If you intend to only call `FreeLibrary` when you are about to exit the process there is no need to do that because everything will be freed anyway.

Comment: When I run the application step by step, it will always do the first and second FreeLibrary, but it will always stop on the 3rd one (no matter which DLL it is, it will always be the last one). If I do not use the FreeLibrary, I am getting an ArithmeticException.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you do `LoadLibrary` some resource get loaded in the library and when you do `FreeLibrary` it hangs because library cannot be unloaded because of such resources still in use.

Maybe these libraries have a method to call for releasing their resources, before calling `FreeLibrary`.